# Calculate $\int_{B_4(0)} \frac{1}{z^2+(i-3)z-3i}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to calculate $\int_{B_4(0)} \frac{1}{z^2+(i-3)z-3i}dz$

using the residue theorem. So to find the zeroes I have that

$$z=\frac{3-i \pm \sqrt{8+6i}}{2}$$

or do I write it as

$$\int_{B_4(0)} \frac{1}{(z-3)(z+i)} dz$$

and do $2 \pi i$  times $(\frac{1}{i-3}+\frac{1}{3+i})$ since $3,-i \in B_4(0)$.

Comment: From the the second expression is easier to estimate the residues. Now write $\frac{1}{(z-3)(z+i)}=\frac{A}{z-3}+\frac{B}{z+i}$ (that is find $A$ and $B$) these are the residues) then direct application if the residue theorem.

Comment: The residue of $(z-a)^{-1}f(z)$ for $f$ analytic at $a$ is equal $f(a).$ Apply that two times: for $a=3,$  $f(z)=(z-i)^{-1}$ and $a=i$, $f(z)=(z-3)^{-1}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Just to pointing out a mistake, $a=i$ is not a pole, but $a=-i$ is a pole.

Comment: @Riemann Thanks. I was typing too fast, and can blame it on my mobile phone.